# Stop the constant random reboots of my GIGABYTE GA-B75M-D3V

Tags: motherboard

I've got some issues with a new system. It's rebooting constantly.

The system consists of a:

brand new:

```
Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3V with F9 BIOS (latest)
Intel Core i5-3470 Ivy Bridge 3.2GHz
2x 8GB G.SKILL Ripjaws 1600MHz memory (mem-tested x-86)
```

replaced old stable system (can run all the below peripherals with no problem):

```
Asus P5K-VM
Core 2 Duo 2.6GHz
2 * 1 + 2 * 2 = 6 GB RAM DDR2
```

coming from a stable system:

```
Creative Soundcard X-FI Titanium
Asus Radeon HD4850
OCZ Vertex 3 120G SSD Sata 3
Hard disk 1TB Sata 2
ASUS Blu-ray Drive 
PSU 400w
3 Fans 120mm
```

Connected peripherals :

```
Toshiba tv (displayport on dvi of MB or HD4850)
Wired mouse, wireless keyboard (logitech)
Bluetooth usb key Azio
```

main problem : it's not possible to read the errors from the MB. nothing on the manual neither on internet.

At the beginning, I received a MB with graphic problems and the problem of rebooting. I RMA'd it. The new one doesn't have any graphic problems. but it's still constantly rebooting.

It's still rebooting with only the ssd, hd, ram, the wireless keyboard and psu. Just browsing internet...

I've got some questions :

- Somebody have an idea of another test?
- The PSU could cause that problem? I used it a lot of years with the stable system.
- Some inputs are coming from the box like sound hd inputs. Could that cause a problem?

BTW, if anyone has the same problem, the manual won't say it but you'll need to reset the bios between two tests (the screwdriver on the two pins) if you suspect a problem of compatibility .

Comment: Disconnect all unnecessary hardware not needed to boot the system, see if it will stabilize, then add hardware one at a time until you find the problem child.

Comment: Do you think it's a realistic idea that a psu cause that problem?

Comment: Possible. The Ivy Bridge can burn up to probably 100W at full load, and your graphics card probably 150-200W, there's little left for the rest. What was your old CPU? And how does it reboot, can you describe it with more detail? What do you see/hear?

Comment: Sure, PSU could cause it. Try it without one of the storage devices and without the Blu-ray player, and see if that helps it any. (and remove the USB key). If that makes a difference, I'd suspect the PSU.

Comment: @Thomas, I updated the old config. and I added 3 system fans. I don't hear anything unusual before the reboot.

Comment: @Mark, It looks like the time between the reboot were shorter with the graphic card (I didn't time it...). If a reboot just happened, the time to the next reboot is really low (a few seconds to a few minutes). I'm going to do a test only ssd and no usb. I will follow up.

Comment: Honestly that sounds like it might be time to return the motherboard again, but I guess it could still be the PSU.

Comment: With only ssd, psu and ram, the problem persists. I'm going to RMA it. Thanks everybody for your assistance.

Comment: What PSU do you have? And have you run a `memtest86+` test yet?

Comment: Finally, I will get refund for this motherboard and get another model from another brand.